# The ideal generated by $2$ and $ x$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the ideal generated by $2$ and $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ all polynomials except for the odd constants?

And is this ideal a non-maximal, prime ideal?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The polynomial $x+1$ is not in $(2,x)$.

Comment: So is this ideal all polynomials except for those with odd constant term?

Comment: Yes, @AlgebraGuy. Or you can think of it as all polynomials with even constant term...

Comment: Is it a non-maximal prime ideal? It seems that $(2)$ and $(x)$ would generate the same ideal. And for any element $ab$ in this ideal, either $a$ or $b$ must also be in it?

Comment: Why do you think $(2)$ generates it? Is $x\in (2)$? Is $2\in(x)$? Why do you think it is non-maximal?

Comment: Ah, yes $x$ is not in $(2)$. What is an example of a non-maximal prime ideal?

Comment: @AlgebraGuy Just $(x)$. Note that $I$ is prime but not maximal iff $R/I$ is a integral domain but not a field.

Comment: How is $(x)$ not maximal? What other ideal can contain it other than $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ itself?

Comment: @AlgebraGuy: An ideal $I$ is maximal if and only if $\mathbb Z[x]/I$ is a field. But $\mathbb Z[x]/(x)=\mathbb Z$ which is not a field.

Answer (score 1):

It is all polynomials with even constant terms. To show this, pick a polynomial $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots +a_1 x + 2a_0$. This is equal to $x\left(a_n x^{n-1} + a_{n-1} x^{n-2} + \cdots +a_1 \right) + 2a_0$, so it's in the ideal.

Showing that polynomials with odd constant terms is just doing this backwards (and shifting the indexing on $a$ appropriately).

EDIT: My ring theory is terrible, but I believe it is maximal.

Say there is an ideal $I$ such that $(2,x) < I$. Then it must contain a polynomial with odd constant term. Let's call it $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots +a_1 x + 2a_0 + 1$. Because $I$ contains $x$ and is contagious under multiplication, $x \left (a_n x^{n-1} + a_{n-1} x^{n-2} + \cdots +a_1 \right) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots +a_1 x$ is in $I$. $I$ is closed under subtraction, so $2a_0 + 1$ is in $I$. Following the same logic with $2$, we see that $1 \in I$, making $I = \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Also, maximal ideals are prime in a commutative ring with $1$.

Comment: Alternatively, you can show that $\mathbb Z[x]/I\cong \mathbb Z/\langle2\rangle$, which is a field, so $I$ is maximal.

Comment: The simplicity of that answer makes me glad I'm taking ring theory next term. :)

Comment: It's just the same proof that you wrote above, but it does add clarity. You still have to prove the isomorphism, which is what you essentially proved.